# Sort IEnumerable<Object> by property and ordered array of those properties

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Given the following:

```
public class Foo
{
  /* other properties */

  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}

var listOfFoo = new[]{
  new Foo { Id = 1 },
  new Foo { Id = 2 },
  new Foo { Id = 3 }
};
var sortOrderIds = new[]{
  2, 3, 1
};
```

If I wanted to sort `listOfFoo` to have the `Id`s end up in the same order as presented in `sortOrderIds`, what's the best way? I assume I could sort using something like:

```
Int32 SortUsingIdArrayAsReference(Foo x, Foo y)
{
  // creative license on "IndexOf", bear with me
  return Int32.CompareTo(sortOrderids.IndexOf(x.Id), sortOrderIds.indexOf(y.Id));
}
```

But is that really the best way to do this? I was hoping LINQ may have something better I could use, but if not oh well. Just looking for other input and see if anyone else has a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`List.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352278.aspx)

```
var ordered = listOfFoo.OrderBy(o => sortOrderIDs.IndexOf(o.Id));
```

**Edit**: Since `sortOrderIDs` is an array:

```
var ordered = listOfFoo.OrderBy(o => Array.IndexOf(sortOrderIds, o.Id));
```

Or, if you want to use the same for lists and arrays, cast it to `IList`:

```
var ordered = listOfFoo.OrderBy(o => ((IList)sortOrderIds).IndexOf(o.Id));
```

Comment: I kind of figured index of was the best bet, but thought I'd see if there was another way. Thanks for the feedback. :-)

Comment: Note that this is a fine solution if the size of the lists are small.  If they are not, then it won't scale well as you're doing a linear search for each item.

Comment: @Servy: Luckily I'm dealing with a small sub-set of data, but what would you propose if this were to be a larger collection?

Comment: @BradChristie: The best way would be to have the list already ordered(f.e. because it comes out of a database). The second best, the order property is part of `Foo`. If you need to store the order in a differnt collection you could use a `Dictionary<int, int>`(the key is the `Id`, the value is the `Index`). But first i would meassure if it's an issue at all, otherwise you're [doing premature optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Was asking for more a general inquiry than for implementation. I'm completely satisfied with `.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(ary, x))`, but doesn't hurt to ask questions. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
var ordered = listOfFoo.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(sortOrderIds, x.Id));
```

This would sort them according to the order of the IDs in `sortOrderIds`. `Foo` objects whose IDs are not found will be at the very top of the resulting list.

If you want them to be at the bottom, change the code like this:

```
var ordered = listOfFoo.OrderBy(x => 
                                {
                                    var idx = Array.IndexOf(sortOrderIds, x.Id);
                                    return idx == -1 ? int.MaxValue : idx;
                                });
```

Comment: Thank you, this was essentially the direction I had planned, just didn't know if there was a better way. Thanks for the quick reply.